# What is the difference between union and text?

Tags: git

At the root of git repo a .gitattributes file. This file contains the following values:

```
*.txt     text merge=text
*.py      text merge=union
```

what is the difference between merge=text and merge=union

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Built-in merge drivers
>
> There are a few built-in low-level merge drivers defined that can be
>   asked for via the merge attribute.
>
> **text:** Usual 3-way file level merge for text files. Conflicted regions
>   are marked with conflict markers <<<<<<<, ======= and >>>>>>>. The
>   version from your branch appears before the ======= marker, and the
>   version from the merged branch appears after the ======= marker.
>
> **binary:** Keep the version from your branch in the work tree, but leave
>   the path in the conflicted state for the user to sort out.
>
> **union:** Run 3-way file level merge for text files, but take lines from
>   both versions, instead of leaving conflict markers. This tends to
>   leave the added lines in the resulting file in random order and the
>   user should verify the result. Do not use this if you do not
>   understand the implications.

Reference: http://schacon.github.io/git/gitattributes.html